# Como eu coloco strings do tipo 'char32_t' e 'char16_t' no console em C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++17

No novo C++17 adicionaram os caracteres `char32_t` e `char16_t`, adicionaram também 'u16string' e 'u32string', mas não criaram nenhum jeito de colocar eles na tela do console.

Por exemplo:

```
int main()
{
    std::u16string u16s{ u"meu teste" }; //até aqui tudo bem.
    std::cout << u16s << std::endl; //não compila, std::cout não aceita u16string
    //não existe std::u16cout nem std::u32cout como existe std::wcout 
}
```

Comment: Tentou usar `wcout`?

Comment: sim, eu tentei isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jeito por enquanto é usar as classes [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) e [`std::wstring_convert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) (apesar de descontinuadas em [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)) para converter uma string em UTF-16 para UTF-8:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::u16string u16str = u"meu teste";
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> codecvt;
    std::string u8str = codecvt.to_bytes(u16str);
    std::cout << u8str << '\n';
}
```

Com a descontinuação dessas classes, não é possível fazer a conversão usando apenas a biblioteca padrão. Entretanto, existe um novo [grupo de estudo de Unicode](https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16) no comitê de C++. Provavelmente, iremos ver novas APIs para esse tipo de trabalho na linguagem.